# Slicing a findall() list for the value

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am recreating a DataCamp exercise using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook and Python 3. The exercise is to import a csv file, create a new column with the value remaining after you use the .replace() method inside a lambda function to remove the dollar sign from the 'total_dollar' column. And then do the same thing again, into another new column, but this time using the RegEx.findall(). Where I run into trouble is using [0] to slice the re.findall() list to get just the value. DataCamp instructions say: Notice that because re.findall() returns a list, you have to slice it in order to access the actual value.

The following code gives me the correct answer on their web site, but not in Jupyter Notebook.

```
tips2 = pd.read_csv('c:\\datacamp\\data\\tips2.csv')
print(tips2.head())

# Write the lambda function using replace
tips2['total_dollar_replace'] = tips2.total_dollar.apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))

# Write the lambda function using regular expressions
tips2['total_dollar_re'] = tips2.total_dollar.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+\.\d+', x)[0])

# Print the head of tips
print(tips2.head())
```

The output is the following:

```
total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size total_dollar
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner   2.0       $16.99
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   3.0       $10.34
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   3.0       $21.01
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   2.0       $23.68
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner   4.0       $24.59


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-598533768fa6> in <module>
     28 
     29 # Write the lambda function using regular expressions
---> 30 tips2['total_dollar_re'] = tips2.total_dollar.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+\.\d+', x)[0])
     31 
     32 

C:\conda\envs\datacamp\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4036             else:
   4037                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4038                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4039 
   4040         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-152-598533768fa6> in <lambda>(x)
     28 
     29 # Write the lambda function using regular expressions
---> 30 tips2['total_dollar_re'] = tips2.total_dollar.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+\.\d+', x)[0])
     31 
     32 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Get rid of the index slicer and the output is better, but not exactly what it should be:

```
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size total_dollar  \
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner   2.0       $16.99   
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   3.0       $10.34   
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   3.0       $21.01   
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner   2.0       $23.68   
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner   4.0       $24.59   

  total_dollar_replace total_dollar_re  
0                16.99         [16.99]  
1                10.34         [10.34]  
2                21.01         [21.01]  
3                23.68         [23.68]  
4                24.59         [24.59]
```

The final column is not supposed to be a list of one, that was supposed to be the point of using the [0] slicer. Your help with understanding what I am missing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't recreate the error. pandas 0.25.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that the `IndexError` is caused by one or more rows for which the regular expression returns no matches. Or in other words, `re.findall()` returns a list of length 0, and you can't index into an empty list. You could get around this problem if you're willing to forgo a lambda function in favor of a full-on function and write something like this:

```py
def my_regex_fun(x):
    try:
        return re.findall('\d+\.\d+', x)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None # Return your choice of whatever here. np.NaN might be a good option

tips2['total_dollar_re'] = tips2.total_dollar.apply(my_regex_fun)
```

This will solve the `IndexError` problems, but not any other problems that might rear their heads.

Comment: Thanks @natemcintosh, your insight is helpful. Your idea that maybe there isn't a match is one I will go a review, but your function worked as expected, thank you for the help.